How did the first CRT monitors with Beam Penetration create a full set of colors?
Was reading about early CRT methods and came across the idea of Beam penetration, which from what I can tell was the first method of using these devices to make color images: two layers of phosphors separated by a distance. If a high energy electron - it excites the green emitting layer, if low, then the red emitting layer.
Resources online (like below) say only 4 colors are possible. red, green, orange and yellow. I wanted to see what such monitors pictures looked like and had a tough time finding an example. Eventually found a youtube video for the 1954 RCA Model CT-100, which was the first color CRT introduced.
This video clearly shows the blue color, which shouldn't be possible with only red/green. So how was this done?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJaOeA6rR64 (Video title: The Very First NTSC Color TV: 1954 RCA Model CT-100 The Merrill - Restoration Part X (Concluded!))
https://www.javatpoint.com/computer-graphics-color-crt-monitors
